# Negative lookahead in XML schema

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I am trying to come up with a regular expression where a string,

- can only be from `[AXYUGHJI]`
- minimum length of the string is 0 and maximum length is 8
- case-insensitive
- must have unique characters only

For example, these are valid strings:

```
axyughji
axgh
agh
h
agHXU
```

whereas these are not.

```
axXgh
axxhu
AXYUGHJIA
ATXYUGHM
```

I know for a fact that XML schema has very limited capabilities, in that they don't have the feature of negative lookaheads which is one of things regex supports in most other languages.

Could the solution be accomplished in a different way?

With the help of negative lookaheads, we can come to a solution. But that is something that is not supported by XML schema.

Answer (score 0):

XSD 1.1 with an assertion on the simple type:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="value" type="value-type" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  
  <xs:simpleType name="value-type">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="0"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="8"/>
        <xs:assertion test="matches($value, '^[axyughji]{0,8}$', 'i') and count(distinct-values(string-to-codepoints(lower-case($value)))) eq string-length($value)"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  
</xs:schema>
```